# Modify a Filters Second Parameter

Tags: filters, references

I have this filter:

```php
$post_arr = apply_filters('insert_product_post_data', $post_arr, $data);
add_filter('insert_product_post_data', 'my_filter', 10, 2);
function my_filter($post_arr, $data) {
    //change $data here
    return $post_arr;
}
```

I need to change the value of $data is any way to do this ?

Comment: No. It’s not possible. And I’m having a hard time imagining why you’d need to do this in your example. Nothing is done with $data in these post data hooks, so modifying it wouldn’t achieve anything.

Comment: i need to do this because the guy who created this plugin closed all the doors to change this data they have verry bad conception

Comment: it's probably worth forking and fixing up the plugin itself if there are serious flaws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this isn't possible without changing the original code. Filters work on the very first parameter, the other parameters are provided for context.

You will need too either get the author to add a filter for the data variable,  fork the plugin, or use a competitor.

The only exception, is if `$data` is an `object` not an `array` and you want to modify it. However, it cannot be replaced, and it cannot be done with an array or any other data type.